# Regex - ignore when exists a certain prefix

Tags: regex

I want to match any number after the letter `v`.

So,

- `v: 123` matches `123`;
- `v 123` matches `123`;
- `v123` matches `123`.

But i want to ignore any match when there's any letter behind `v`.

Like `xv: 123` must not match anything.

I'm working with this pattern:

```
/v[\s\pP]*(\d+)/
```

but it doesn't ignore situations when `somethingbehindv: 123`.

Comment: What named property are you referencing with `\pP`? And do you want `v123` to match?

Comment: `\pP` matches any kind of punctuation character.

Comment: Ah, duh, okay. And do you want `v123` to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [word boundary `\b`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) to fix your problem:

```
/\bv[\s\pP]*(\d+)/
```

Comment: Cool answer! Not related but your explanation was generated by some kind of website? :)

Comment: Hmm i can approve your answer but you should update it since your pattern matches situations like `vaaa: 123`

Comment: Just a space or an punctuation char. Anyway, your "explainer" isn't working with this pattern :\

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to use a [negative look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This is an extended regular expression and may not supported in whatever language or platform you're using. It would look something like this:

```
/(?<!\S)v[\s\pP]*(\d+)/
```

Which basically prevents the pattern from matching if any non-whitespace character(s) (`\S`) precede the `v`. You can tweak this, of course, if other characters should be disallowed.

Comment: Probably a better option if supported. Thanks!